# How to put a framed box around text + math environment

Tags: framed

I am looking for something like `\fbox` but it seems that you cannot use it when a math environment is included. However its not only a math environment (then you could use `\boxed` I know) but also text, I need to be in a frame.

example:

```
\rdmframeboxaroundwhatever{

blablabla

\begin{align}
Formula of the universe
\end{align}


Hoaray

}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11484/how-to-draw-a-frame-box-around-an-arbitrary-large-piece-of-text-figures-whatever

Answer (score 128):

You can also use `tcolorbox`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}

blablabla

\begin{align}
E &= mc^2 & \text{Formula of the universe}
\end{align}


Hoaray

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we change the color and embrossment of the box..I expect the box must me like our "add comment" box, and letter must be shown like that.. Can I do?@peter

Comment: @David: Sure, pretty much everything can be customized. The `tcolorbox` manual should have the desired info. If you are unable to locate the desired info I would suggest you post a new question as your question is about customizing a `tcolorbox` which is independent of if it is around math or text. In the question describe or show exactly what you want and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: NOTE: The blank lines _before_ `\begin{align}` and _after `\end{align}` should be eliminated.

Comment: How to change the shade of box

Comment: @user716881: Not sure exactly what you want, but you can try using `\begin{tcolorox][colback=yellow]` for instance. There are numerous other options, so you should search for `tcolorbox` on this site, see the `tcolorbox` documentation or post a new question regarding a specfic style you want to see.

Comment: Cannot believe that the `tcolorbox` documentation is 530pp long. I hoped to have a quick feel of the package by looking at the "examples" pdf, but that's 8pp of colored boxes... without the source code! I'll use the `mdframed` package instead, for its neat and simple documentation. I'm still so impressed by latex's complexity for doing such trivial things as `style={background-color: #fba; border: 1px solid #432; padding: 20px}`... :'(

Comment: @shevket: Yep, the package is growing. I strted of with mdframed and have slowly been dwithcing over to tcolorbox as it is a lot more flexible and has ongoing support.  For simple cases, `tcolrobox` is pretty straight forward. Then, when you need to tweak somehting you can look for the required settings. I find that way of learnign works for me.

Comment: When I do this around the first paragraph in en enumerate environment, the number ends aligned vertically with the middle of the paragraph instead of with the top of it. How can I change so that it aligns with the top?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: Best to post a new question. Please include a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks. I ended up using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448771/14212).

Answer (score 66):

You could take a look at [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), which also allows pagebreaks, and allows you to customize the look of the frame. A simple example, which puts a box similar to `\fbox` around the content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for creating dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \sin(x)
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

A second example, showing some more of what the package can do. See the manual for the full story.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    linecolor=blue,
    outerlinewidth=2pt,
    roundcorner=20pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!50!white}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \sin(x)
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I control the width? At the moment, it's taking the entire horizontal space of the page.

Comment: @xxx--- `userdefinedwidth=10cm`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. where do I put that?

Comment: @SPSharan Along with the other settings in the definition of the `MyFrame` style.

Answer (score 17):

Wrap the math and text in a `minipage`, then put that in the `fbox`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{4 in}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed fringilla
purus bibendum odio ultricies non bibendum massa condimentum. Morbi
scelerisque pulvinar quam, sed porta ipsum blandit ac.
\begin{equation}
    \frac{Lorem}{Ipsum}=Do^2lr+\int_i^t\,d(amet)
\end{equation}
Sed felis arcu, pretium ut vulputate at, feugiat vitae orci. In hac
habitasse platea dictumst. Integer mollis vulputate dui. Fusce
eget sollicitudin purus.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't break across pages whereas the `mdframed` solution will.

Comment: `\fbox{` worked with Geogebra (linux) :)

Answer (score 9):

I'm actually a TeX noob, so use this with caution, but I saw an approach in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42437/63815) which makes the box *tight*, that is, it's exactly as wide and tall as the equation makes it be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{collectbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mybox}{%
    \collectbox{%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
        \fbox{\BOXCONTENT}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mybox{$\left(\nabla_X Y\right)^k = X^i (\nabla_i Y)^k = X^i \left(\frac{\partial Y^k}{\partial x^i} + \Gamma^k{}_{im} Y^m\right)$}
\mybox{$\nabla_{\mathbf{u}_i}\mathbf{u}_j = \omega^k{}_{ij}\mathbf{u}_k$}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know how to change the border colors for the box?

Comment: @Masoud I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 7):

My combination of a frame box and math (trying to align the formula vertically as well as horizontally - give more space when the math gets really tall and allow more room horizontally for better visual effect):

```
\framebox{

\parbox[t][1.0cm]{4.50cm}{

\addvspace{0.2cm} \centering 

$ p \;=\; -\, \dfrac{17}{23}\;;\; \quad q \;=\; \dfrac{10}{23} $ 

} 

}\\
```

[image]

Comment: Tip: You can mark code sch as I did in my edit by either indenting it with four spaces, or selecting the block and clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field (keyboard shortcut, Ctrl + K).

Answer (score 5):

You can put the text in a `\mbox` and use `\boxed`. Example:

```
\begin{document}
$\boxed{\sin \theta \mbox{blablablablablabla}}$
\end{document}
```

This should produce a box around both sin theta and blablablablablabla.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  As it stands your answer is not compilable, `\boxed` is not a standard LaTeX command.  Also this does not answer the question, which is about boxes around material including displayed mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

```
    \begin{document}
     \color{red}
      \begin{center}
        \framebox{


       \parbox[t][1.0cm]{4.50cm}{


       \color{blue}
       \begin{tabular}{c}
         \\
       $ E^2=p^2c^2+m_{0}c^4 $ 
       \end{tabular}

         } 

        }
       \end{center}
```

This does not use any packages and we have full freedom to play with it.
\end{document}