# Text in squared box

Tags: boxes, framed

I'd like to bot a *square* box around some text. I'd like to denote a labelled object of size 1, in combinatorics this is often symbolised by something like `\boxed{1}`. It would be nicer if the box was a square. Is there an adequate command for this?

Comment: So even if your text is not "square", you want to place a square box around it?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: You are right, that's a problem for beauty. But the square is used in graph theory for leaves of trees and I want to adopt this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here a solution based on my `collectbox` package. This makes it support verbatim and other special text.

It doesn't change the baseline of the content, which is what you normally want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collectbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sqbox}{%
    \collectbox{%
        \@tempdima=\dimexpr\width-\totalheight\relax
        \ifdim\@tempdima<\z@
            \fbox{\hbox{\hspace{-.5\@tempdima}\BOXCONTENT\hspace{-.5\@tempdima}}}%
        \else
            \ht\collectedbox=\dimexpr\ht\collectedbox+.5\@tempdima\relax
            \dp\collectedbox=\dimexpr\dp\collectedbox+.5\@tempdima\relax
            \fbox{\BOXCONTENT}%
        \fi
    }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}% just for the example text
\begin{document}

.. \sqbox{Text} .. \sqbox{Very very long Text} .. \sqbox{\scalebox{.1}[10]{Stretched}} .. \sqbox{$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{10} x_k = i$} .. \sqbox{\verb+$%^&+}


\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

Alternatively you can avoid the package and box the content directly:

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sqbox}[1]{%
    \@begin@tempboxa\hbox{#1}%
    \@tempdima=\dimexpr\width-\totalheight\relax
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\z@
        \fbox{\hbox{\hspace{-.5\@tempdima}\usebox\@tempboxa\hspace{-.5\@tempdima}}}%
    \else
        \ht\@tempboxa=\dimexpr\ht\@tempboxa+.5\@tempdima\relax
        \dp\@tempboxa=\dimexpr\dp\@tempboxa+.5\@tempdima\relax
        \fbox{\usebox\@tempboxa}%
    \fi
    \@end@tempboxa
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}% For example only
\begin{document}

\noindent
.. \sqbox{Text} .. \sqbox{Very very long Text} .. \sqbox{\scalebox{.1}[10]{Stretched}} .. \sqbox{$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{10} x_k = i$} .. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You **can really change** the box dimensions with `\ht,\dp,\wd` commands? Please confirm that I read your code correctly, because it would turn boxes into even more powerful weapon!

Comment: @tohecz: yes, you can change the box dimensions! However `\advance\ht\mybox by <somevalue>`, aka. `\addtolength` doesn't work, just straight assignments. You need to pay attention if you change the width because you only add (or remove) space from the right. It is better to re-box the content with added horizontal space like above. Check the code of my `adjustbox` package especially `\marginbox` and `\trimbox` if you want to see more.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the mandatory overkill `tikz` version. Since it is uses `tikz` all the flexibility inherent in `tikz` is available to customize the square:

[image]

### Notes:

- Will not work if the text is very long unless it is placed in a `\parbox`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@myBoxHeight%
\newdimen\@myBoxDepth%
\newdimen\@myBoxWidth%
\newdimen\@myBoxSize%
\newcommand{\SquareBox}[2][]{%
    \settoheight{\@myBoxHeight}{#2}% Record height of box
    \settodepth{\@myBoxDepth}{#2}% Record depth of box
    \settowidth{\@myBoxWidth}{#2}% Record width of box
    \pgfmathsetlength{\@myBoxSize}{max(\@myBoxWidth,(\@myBoxHeight+\@myBoxDepth))}%
    \tikz \node [shape=rectangle, shape aspect=1,draw=red,inner sep=2\pgflinewidth, minimum size=\@myBoxSize,#1] {#2};%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\SquareBox{I}
\SquareBox{y}
\SquareBox[thick, dashed]{long text}
\SquareBox[draw=blue]{longer text}
\SquareBox[draw=blue, thick, fill=yellow]{$e = mc^2$}
\SquareBox[draw=black, thick, fill=yellow!10, rounded corners=2pt]{$\displaystyle \int_{-\dfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} dx $}
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks nice, you just need to do the vertical correction (the "raise value" is `-0.5*(myBoxSize-1.2*myBoxHeight+1.2*myBoxDepth)`)

Comment: @tohecz: not sure what you mean. Is that related to why I needed the `1.2` fudge factor?

Comment: I think that it is better to align the boxes by their baseline and not by their bottom. Check the line `\setlength{\@tempdimb}{(\@tempdima-\ht1+\dp1)/2}` in my code, it deals with the vertical correction. I was just suggesting you the same correction, because obviously your answer uses `tikz` with all its features ;)

Comment: @tohecz: It does not appear as if it is necessary, the contents appeared to be centered already.

Comment: @PeterGrill: You can set the key `text width`. In this case you don't need a `\parbox`.

Answer (score 8):

This should work for you. It does the necessary vertical corrections so that the text is on a baseline (the same vertical level as the surrounding text). You can change the `\fboxsep` line to get more or less tight box.

**Edit:** I removed the `\smash` command, now even constructions like `$\left(\Sq{12345}^n\right)$` work.

**Edit 2:** Added `\textSq` for text-mode contents and modified `\Sq` to accept math-mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\def\textSq#1{%
\begingroup% make boxes and lengths local
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.3ex}% SET ANY DESIRED PADDING HERE
\setbox1=\hbox{#1}% save the contents
\setlength{\@tempdima}{\maxof{\wd1}{\ht1+\dp1}}% size of the box
\setlength{\@tempdimb}{(\@tempdima-\ht1+\dp1)/2}% vertical raise
\raise-\@tempdimb\hbox{\fbox{\vbox to \@tempdima{%
  \vfil\hbox to \@tempdima{\hfil\copy1\hfil}\vfil}}}%
\endgroup%
}
\def\Sq#1{\textSq{\ensuremath{#1}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello \textSq{1} world! $f(x):=\Sq1+\Sq2$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Needs a slight tweak: It should be `\setbox1=\hbox{\ensuremath{#1}}` to be able to handle the case of `$f(x):=\Sq1+\Sq{x^2}$`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks. As I'm really not a fan of `\ensuremath` (it is somehow a "non-predictable" command), so I made it into 2 commands.

Comment: You're solution is good. Don't know what you mean by "non-predictable". Maybe you [have been hanging around @egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)? :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill Well, I want a macro that produces text in text-mode and math in math-mode. The command `\ensuremath` does something you **should never need**, because you---the typesetter---is the one who controls the code, and you should not give this control to such commands.

Comment: @PeterGrill To a specific example: If I defined `\Sq` using `\ensuremath`, then someone can come, write `\Sq{x^2}+\Sq{y^2}` and he would think what a nice math-mode construction he made, however, it is not a math-mode, but two math-modes with a text-mode `+` in-between.

Answer (score 5):

tohecz just beat me to it. Here is an alternative version:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\spacer}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand{\squarebox}[1]{%
\sbox\mybox{#1}%
\setlength{\spacer}{0.5\wd\mybox-0.5\ht\mybox}%
\fbox{\parbox{\wd\mybox}{\vspace{\spacer}\usebox\mybox\vspace{\spacer}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\squarebox{does this look great or what?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the text in the box is a bit vertically mal-positioned: `\squarebox{boxed text \_\_}\_\_ baseline`

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution that uses `pstricks` the great [Herbert Voss offered some years ago](http://de.narkive.com/2004/4/1/745732-re-frage-zu-pstricks-psframebox.html):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % for easy pdf-output - otherwise comment this out

\def\bBox#1#2{\makebox[#1]{#2}}
\def\bhBox#1#2{\parbox[c][#1][c]{#1}{\makebox[#1]{#2}}}
\def\bhpBox#1#2{\parbox[c][#1][c]{#1}{\centering #2}}

\begin{document}
%\psset{framesep=0}
\psframebox{\bBox{1.3cm}{A}} und \psframebox{\bBox{1.3cm}{BBBBB}}

\psframebox{\bhBox{1.3cm}{A}} und \psframebox{\bhBox{1.3cm}{BBBBB}}

\psframebox{\bhpBox{1.3cm}{A}} und \psframebox{\bhpBox{1.3cm}{BBBBB}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is a solution based on ConTeXt. I define a special `\framed` for the task, so all the options of `\framed` work:

```
\unprotect 
\newdimen\d_square_size 

\defineframed[squared_box] 
             [ 
               \c!location=\v!lohi, 
               \c!width=\d_square_size, 
               \c!height=\d_square_size, 
             ]  

\def\squared_and_framed_box 
    {\ifdim\wd\nextbox>\dimexpr(\ht\nextbox+\dp\nextbox)\relax 
        \d_square_size=\wd\nextbox 
     \else 
        \d_square_size=\dimexpr\ht\nextbox+\dp\nextbox\relax 
     \fi 
     \squared_box{\box\nextbox}% 
     \endgroup 
     } 

\def\squarebox 
    {\dosingleargument\squarebox_indeed} 

\def\squarebox_indeed[#1]% 
    {\begingroup 
     \setupframed[squared_box][#1]% 
     \dowithnextbox\squared_and_framed_box\hbox} 
\protect 

\starttext 
\unknown\squarebox{ABCDEF} 
\unknown\squarebox[framecolor=red]{A very long text} 
\unknown\squarebox[corner=round]{$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n$} 
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

You can add a `offset=<dimen>` to the `\defineframed` command to have some offset between the text and the frame.