# Is it possible to create an adaptable golden ratio frame around equations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, framed

I would like to create special frame around my equations. This frame should obey to the **golden ratio** rule. This means that its width divided by its height should give **1.61803398875**.

If possible, the code will adapt to choose the *long* side. For example for a long column vector, the height will be 1.61803398875 times longer than its width.

I've found the following code in another question in this forum ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42406/text-in-squared-box)). It uses `tikz` but I can't figure out how to modify it to obtain a golden ratio frame around my equations...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@myBoxHeight%
\newdimen\@myBoxDepth%
\newdimen\@myBoxWidth%
\newdimen\@myBoxSize%
\newcommand{\SquareBox}[2][]{%
    \settoheight{\@myBoxHeight}{#2}% Record height of box
    \settodepth{\@myBoxDepth}{#2}% Record depth of box
    \settowidth{\@myBoxWidth}{#2}% Record width of box
    \pgfmathsetlength{\@myBoxSize}{max(\@myBoxWidth,(\@myBoxHeight+\@myBoxDepth))}%
    \tikz \node [shape=rectangle, shape aspect=1,draw=red,inner sep=2\pgflinewidth, minimum size=\@myBoxSize,#1] {#2};%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\SquareBox{I}
\SquareBox{y}
\SquareBox[thick, dashed]{long text}
\SquareBox[draw=blue]{longer text}
\SquareBox[draw=blue, thick, fill=yellow]{$e = mc^2$}
\SquareBox[draw=black, thick, fill=yellow!10, rounded corners=2pt]{$\displaystyle \int_{-\dfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} dx $}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Horizontal GoldenBox

Here is a (*pure TikZ*!) solution via the `fit`, `calc` and `backgrounds` TikZ libraries where all equations are horizontally aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,backgrounds}

\pgfmathsetmacro\goldenratio{(1+sqrt(5))/2}
\newcommand\GoldenBox[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(eq.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0] (eq) {#2};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \path let \p1=(eq.south west), \p2=(eq.north east),
      \n{boxw}={max(\x2-\x1,(\y2-\y1)*\goldenratio)},
      \n{boxh}={\n{boxw}/\goldenratio}
      in node [rectangle,fit=(eq),draw=red,inner sep=2*\pgflinewidth,
      minimum width=\n{boxw},minimum height=\n{boxh},#1] {};%
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\GoldenBox{I}
\GoldenBox{y}
\GoldenBox[thick, dashed]{long text}
\GoldenBox[draw=blue]{longer text}
\GoldenBox[draw=blue, thick, fill=yellow]{$e = mc^2$}
\GoldenBox[draw=black, thick, fill=yellow!10, rounded corners=2pt]
{$\displaystyle \int_{-\dfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} dx $}
\end{document}
```

### Vertical or Horizontal GoldenBox

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,backgrounds}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfmathsetmacro\goldenratio{(1+sqrt(5))/2}
\newcommand\GoldenBox[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(eq.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0] (eq) {#2};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \path let
      \p1=(eq.south west), \p2=(eq.north east),
      \n{w}={\x2-\x1}, \n{h}={\y2-\y1},
      \n{boxw}={\n{w}>=\n{h}?max(\n{w},\n{h}*\goldenratio):max(\n{w},\n{h}/\goldenratio)},
      \n{boxh}={\n{w}>=\n{h}?max(\n{w}/\goldenratio,\n{h}):max(\n{h}:\n{w}*\goldenratio)}
      in node [rectangle,fit=(eq),draw=red,inner sep=2*\pgflinewidth,
      minimum width=\n{boxw},minimum height=\n{boxh},#1] {};%
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\GoldenBox{I}
\GoldenBox{y}
\GoldenBox[thick, dashed]{long text}
\GoldenBox[draw=blue]{longer text}
\GoldenBox[draw=blue, thick, fill=yellow]{$e = mc^2$}
\GoldenBox[draw=black, thick, fill=yellow!10, rounded corners=2pt]
{$\displaystyle \int_{-\dfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} dx $}
\GoldenBox[draw=black, thick, fill=yellow!10, rounded
corners=2pt]{$\displaystyle
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6
\end{pmatrix}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact I was having this issue in a document just some minutes ago... Will it be possible to make this box choose the **long** side and *flip* the box according to it (for example for a long column vector...)?

Comment: @jrojasqu I edited my anwser.

Answer (score 15):

The adaptation is not so hard.  You need dimensions for the width *and* height:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@myBoxHeight%
\newdimen\@myBoxDepth%
\newdimen\@myBoxWidth%
\newdimen\@myBoxW%
\newdimen\@myBoxH%
\newcommand{\GoldenBox}[2][]{%
    \settoheight{\@myBoxHeight}{#2}% Record height of box
    \settodepth{\@myBoxDepth}{#2}% Record depth of box
    \settowidth{\@myBoxWidth}{#2}% Record width of box
    \pgfmathsetlength{\@myBoxW}{max(\@myBoxWidth,(\@myBoxHeight+\@myBoxDepth)*1.61803398875)}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\@myBoxH}{\@myBoxW/1.61803398875}
    \tikz \node [shape=rectangle, shape aspect=1,draw=red,inner
    sep=2\pgflinewidth, minimum width=\@myBoxW,minimum height=\@myBoxH,#1] {#2};%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\GoldenBox{I}
\GoldenBox{y}
\GoldenBox[thick, dashed]{long text}
\GoldenBox[draw=blue]{longer rambling text}
\GoldenBox[draw=blue, thick, fill=yellow]{$e = mc^2$}
\GoldenBox[draw=black, thick, fill=yellow!10, rounded
corners=2pt]{$\displaystyle
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6
\end{pmatrix}$}
\end{document}
```