# fontawesome5 monospaced icons

Tags: typewriter, fontawesome

I have been trying to make icons from [fontawesome5](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) monospaced without much success:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
  \section{MWE}
  The \faIcon{desktop} and \faIcon{mobile} icons should be the same width.
\end{document}
```

I tried wrapping the `\faIcon{}` commands in `\texttt{}`, which did nothing.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In the meantime, I found an answer to the question that I feel is a bit of an overkill: wrapping the symbols in square boxes, as suggested in the accepted answer of [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42406/text-in-squared-box).

Isn't there a better way?

Comment: It is. Should I flag the question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use the "fixed" package option, `\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
  \section{MWE}
  The \faIcon{desktop} and \faIcon{mobile} icons should be the same width.

rmfamily:\\
\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\\
\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}

\ttfamily 
ttfamily:\\
\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\faIcon{desktop}\\
\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}\faIcon{mobile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the fixed widths can vary if, for example, you are in a different font family such as `\ttfamily`.  They will still be fixed width, just a different fixed width from `\rmfamily`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that in the package documentation. Thank you!