# Framed text using latex

Tags: tables, framed, text

I was wondering how to generate this using LaTeX.[image]

I have seen articles like [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204888/26232) but it only gives me for only a subset of what I wanted to do.

Comment: What have you got so far? We are no do-it-for-me service, but willing to help if you support us. Please add a MWE.

Comment: I used exactly the suggestions given the in the link attached. I can add the MWE.

Comment: Well, that isn't a MWE connected to your problem. You could at least have tried to customize it to your needs (black/white, sharp corners). See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `tcolorbox`. Please read the manual for further customization options (it's very detailed).

[image: tcb]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster after skip=0pt,raster column skip=0pt]
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,colback=white,colframe=black]
\footnotesize (Nombre, apellidos y firma)\\\normalsize\vskip2\baselineskip
Presidente/a
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,colback=white,colframe=black]
\footnotesize (Nombre, apellidos y firma)\\\normalsize\vskip2\baselineskip
Secretario/a
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster before skip=-1pt,raster column skip=0pt]
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,colback=white,colframe=black] 
\footnotesize (Nombre, apellidos y firma)\\\normalsize\vskip2\baselineskip
Vocal
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,colback=white,colframe=black] 
\footnotesize (Nombre, apellidos y firma)\\\normalsize\vskip2\baselineskip
Vocal
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,colback=white,colframe=black] 
\footnotesize (Nombre, apellidos y firma)\\\normalsize\vskip2\baselineskip
Vocal
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```