# Aligning tcolorbox in enumerates to first baseline

Tags: align, tcolorbox

I have lost hours to this... How do I align a series of tcolorboxes based on the first baseline (or a certain mm of shift). I'll have somewhere around 60 of these per document, and 15 documents...I need a fix! Or an alternative way to the same visual result

What I have:

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{sharp corners, frame hidden, boxrule=0mm, colframe=white, box align=top}
```

later in document

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{tcolorbox}{(Proof 1.1) For $a$ and $b$, two elements of a Field $F$, using only the axioms for a field, proofs:}\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{itemize}
\item \openq $\forall a \in F$, $0a = 0$ \closeq
```

...

There has to be a way...

[image: The grey boxes need to line up with the first line NEXT to the number/bullet]

Comment: Also, I'd defined these, to clear confusion: \newcommand{\openq}{\begin{tcolorbox}}
\newcommand{\closeq}{\end{tcolorbox}}

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i) please provide small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending by `\end{document}`! (ii) do you really need `tcolorbox`? from image i see that `colorbox` from `the `xcolor` package should be suficient and better suited to your need.

Comment: @Zarko Apologies, will post complete latex next time!
tcolorbox is needed because with colorbox I couldn't get good text wrap and spacing settings - which I need for some longer section blocks as the document progresses.

Answer (score 5):

I propose this hack, with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Character set
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{sharp corners, frame hidden, boxrule=0mm, colframe=white, box align=top}
\newcommand{\openq}{\begin{tcolorbox}}
\newcommand{\closeq}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\makeatletter
\def\tcbboxsep{\kvtcb@boxsep}
\def\tcbtopsep{\kvtcb@topsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr2\baselineskip + \tcbboxsep + \tcbtopsep}
\begin{tcolorbox}{(Proof 1.1) For $a$ and $b$, two elements of a Field $F$, using only the axioms for a field, proofs:}\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr2\baselineskip + \tcbboxsep +\tcbtopsep}
\openq $\forall a \in F$, $0\,a = 0$ \closeq
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bernard! Took me a bit of internet digging to understand what the string `\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr2\baselineskip + \tcbboxsep + \tcbtopsep}` was doing, other than fixing my problem! I used it without the added sep, and adding some additional spacing of my own that I wanted, but this was a great hack! I put it into a command so that it applies across the board.

Comment: I don't always explain the details of a code, if I think it would be lengthy and not very useful for the average user. However, I very gladly explain when I'm asked to,so really  feel free to ask!

Comment: I’m afraid a page break can occur after the `\vspace*{...}`. I’m not sure that adding `\nopagebreak` would fix it, some experiments are in order.

Comment: @egreg: It's only a proposed hack… Please let me know if you find problems.