# Choose size of text inside a framed box and align it with the text width

Tags: align, fontsize, mdframed

I am using a framed box to put forward some texts. I have two problems:

- First, I would like to minimize the text size; as we can do for the legend of a figure: `\captionsetup{width=0.95\textwidth, font=small}`.
- Secondly, I have a problem with my alignment as regards the text. The framed boxes stay on the right at each page. I suspect a problem with all the others packages. That's why they are all here. *Sorry for the long list.*

Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}

% I put all packages to prevent any conflict

\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
\documentclass[12pt, french, onehalfspacing, headsepline, table,]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true, doi = false, url=false, arxiv=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype, mparhack, relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{width=0.95\textwidth, font=small}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

% End of the long list


%Needed for the framed box: 

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    linecolor=blue,
    outerlinewidth=2pt,
    roundcorner=20pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!50!white}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \sin(x)
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand the first question. The second question, the boxes being a bit shifted to the right, is due to the paragraph indent. But i don't understand why you put the framed box iin a `parbox`? What do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: Package `minitoc` and this class are incompatible. See https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=97529#p97529

Comment: You can use `\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-40pt}` because of the margins of your framed box