# Creating a LaTeX box

Tags: math-mode, tcolorbox, boxes

I'm taking some notes for my math class and I would like to create a box like so to separate important points and examples so that it doesn't look so cluttered:

[image]

I'm not sure what it uses, but could someone help me out with some starter code and ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a framed box around text + math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36524/how-to-put-a-framed-box-around-text-math-environment)

Comment: Not completely but it has a general idea. I was looking for a specific type of box setting so that I could understand how to use it in this case. Thanks for the link to the other question though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These boxes are easy to do with [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). For theorems and definitions, there is a nice library `theorems` which provides a lot of useful commands; see chapter 18 in the documentation.

To help you get started, here's an example with a good approximation of the image you provided.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{definition}{Definition}{
    sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=red!20!white,
    colback=red!10!white,
    boxrule=0mm,
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}{Probability space}{}
A \textbf{probability space} is a triple \((\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)\):
\begin{itemize}
    \item \(\Omega =\) ``sample space'' = set of ``samples''
    \item \(\mathcal{F} =\) family of subsets of \(\Omega\), called ``events''
    \item \(P = \) probability measure
\end{itemize}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```